# How to hide can't selecting date in datePicker on flutter?

Tags: flutter, datepicker, flutter-dependencies

My UI

[image: ![enter image description here]

In this datePicker only can select maximum of 2 years and 29days from today (6/10/2020), the minimum day is 1 year from today(5/11//2021), So I want to hide other dates ( can't select years) How to do that?
Ex: From Today maximum year is 2020 so want to hide 2019,2018,2017......
And minimum year is 2021 so want hide 2022

code

```
import 'package:age_calculator/age_calculator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BirthdayScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BirthdayScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BirthdayScreen> createState() => _BirthdayScreenState();
}

class _BirthdayScreenState extends State<BirthdayScreen> {
  // 1st dropdown button
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  //date picker
  DateTime? selectedDate;
  DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
  void showDatePicker() {
    DateTime mindate = DateTime(now.year - 2, now.month, now.day - 29);
    DateTime maxdate = DateTime(now.year - 1, now.month, now.day);
    showCupertinoModalPopup(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext builder) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height * 0.25,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: CupertinoDatePicker(
              mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
              initialDateTime: mindate,
              onDateTimeChanged: (value) {
                if (value != selectedDate) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedDate = value;
                    'Birthday'
                        '${selectedDate?.year}/${selectedDate?.month}/${selectedDate?.day} ';
                    calAge();
                  });
                }
              },
              maximumDate: maxdate,
              minimumDate: mindate,
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  String age = "";
  DateDuration? duration;
  getAge(DateTime fromDate) =>
      DateTime.now().difference(fromDate).inDays ~/ 365;

  void calAge() {
    DateTime? birthday = selectedDate;

    setState(() {
      duration = AgeCalculator.age(birthday!);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(duration);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 100),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.brightness_1,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 10,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                      child: Text("birthday",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          )),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 110.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: DecoratedBox(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              selectedDate == null
                                  ? 'Birthday'
                                  : '${selectedDate?.year}/${selectedDate?.month}/${selectedDate?.day} ',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 30.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 88.0,
                        height: 25.0,
                        child: MaterialButton(
                          onPressed: showDatePicker,
                          shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          child: const Text(
                            'select',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: 0.0,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 160.0,
                height: 35.0,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                          side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('next')),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **maximumYear and minimumYear** Properties that's already avaliable in CupertinoDatePicker class.

```
// This code will hide all the years except 2021 and 2020 only
CupertinoDatePicker(
     maximumYear:2021,
     minimumYear : 2020,
     initialDateTime: date,
)
```

Hope this answer help you and thanks.